# Typo in Bourbaki's "Functions of a Real Variable", p. 194?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Toward the end of page 194 of Bourbaki's [*Functions of a Real Variable*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-59315-4), the following is stated:

> [...] the $n$ functions $t^k e^{r_j t}$ ($1\leq k\leq n_j$, $1\leq j\leq q$) are linearly independent integrals of the homogeneous equation (41).

Shouldn't it say $t^{k-1} e^{r_j t}$? I mean, if the root $r_j$ is of multiplicity 1, then, as far as I'm aware, the associated solution is $e^{r_j t}$, and not $t e^{r_j t}$, right?

Screenshot of part of the page in question, for reference:

[image: Screenshot of part of page 194 of Bourbaki's "Functions of a Real Variable"]

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Okay, that's very reassuring, thank you!